# I get the error: incorrect table definition

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, create-table

Im using phpmyadmin for the first time and I get this error: incorrect table definition. there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as key. What am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE `database_reservering`.`formData` ( 
`nameTeacher` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
`nameChild` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
`age` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
`date` DATE NOT NULL , 
`comment` VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
`id` INT(30) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
 PRIMARY KEY (`nameTeacher`)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Auto_increment column has to be primary key. You might also want a unique key on nameteacher.

Comment: @Micha . . . What part of the message do you not understand?  It seems quite clear:  `id` is an auto-increment column but you have declared `nameTeacher` to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message is:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

The problem is that you have `id` as auto-increment, but the primary key is on `nameTeacher`. This is not allowed. You can change the statement to make `id` the primary key, and put a unique constraint on `nameTeacher`. This implements the same logic, but is valid MySQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `formData` ( 
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE (`nameTeacher`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eed4e28923f8c6d61ca689bad491642c)**

Answer (score 0):

Change
PRIMARY KEY (`nameTeacher`)
to
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Full statement:

```
CREATE TABLE formData ( 
nameTeacher VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, 
nameChild VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
age INT(11) NOT NULL , 
`date` DATE NOT NULL , 
`comment` VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve when PK is set to the column other than AUTO_INCREMENT?

If you want to have separate independent autoincremented sequence for each `nameTeacher` value then alter the engine to MyISAM and define PK like `(nameTeacher, id)`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `formData` ( 
    `nameTeacher` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `nameChild` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `age` INT(11) NOT NULL , `date` DATE NOT NULL , 
    `comment` VARCHAR(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , 
    `id` INT(30) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`nameTeacher`, `id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b55ac68fd5b4251d0f065e43838d67f8)

See [Using AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for details.